# How to flatten d3.nest using javascript map() method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have some data that I've nested with d3. I now want to flatten it. I'm trying to use the `map()` method to do this, but I am getting errors.

This is the error I'm seeing in my console log -- related to line 24 (where I try to get `item.values[i].key`):

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of
> undefined

I don't see where I'm going wrong and I've spent hours googling. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053325/d3-js-flattening-nested-data) is similar, but it wasn't answered. It seems like this should be straightforward.

What am I missing? Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

const mhData = axios.get("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR-MzpkhMmVMkwmhKFvjPyru5LlYPvWo7_xU8ZARbQmdWP9AIh1VXhZ1aWLWR_PgAySq4gobndfpWP0/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv")
    .then(content => {

        const justData = content.data
        const csv = d3.csvParse(justData)

        const nestedData = d3.nest()
            .key(d => d.date)
            .key(d => d.industry)
            .rollup(v => d3.sum(v, d => d.value))
            .entries(csv)
            console.log('nestedData',nestedData)


        const flattenData = nestedData.map((item,i) => ({
            date: item.key,
            industry: item.values[i].key,
            value: item.values[i].value
        }));
        console.log('flattenData',flattenData)
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of data before the flattening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code: `nestedData.map((item,i) => ({...`, `i` is an index of `nestedData` not `values` - which is why you are running into errors.

Your `nest` returns a single level of nesting e.g.

```
nestedData [
  {
    "key": "2020-01-07",
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "Tech",
        "value": 1352
      },
      {
        "key": "Media",
        "value": 2848
      },
      ...
```

So within your `map` you need a single nested `map`. You can also change your 'outer' `map` to [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) which will then return an array of objects.

I took a small sample of your data to accompany the working example below:

```js
const csv = mockData();
//console.log(csv);

const nestedData = d3.nest()
  .key(d => d.date)
  .key(d => d.industry)
  .rollup(v => d3.sum(v, d => d.value))
  .entries(csv)
//console.log('nestedData',nestedData);

const flattenData = nestedData.flatMap((item, i) => {
  const date = item.key;
  return item.values.map(industry => ({
    date: date,
    industry: industry.key,
    value: industry.value
  }));
});
console.log('flattenData', flattenData);

function mockData() {
  const str = `date,industry,gender,value
2020-01-07,Tech,Men,1004
2020-01-07,Tech,Women,348
2020-01-07,Media,Men,2468
2020-01-07,Media,Women,380
2020-01-07,Real Estate,Men,1214
2020-01-07,Real Estate,Women,391
2020-01-14,Tech,Men,989
2020-01-14,Tech,Women,357
2020-01-14,Media,Men,2430
2020-01-14,Media,Women,393
2020-01-14,Real Estate,Men,1322
2020-01-14,Real Estate,Women,366
2020-01-21,Tech,Men,975
2020-01-21,Tech,Women,339
2020-01-21,Media,Men,2416
2020-01-21,Media,Women,388
2020-01-21,Real Estate,Men,1336
2020-01-21,Real Estate,Women,3581`;

  return d3.csvParse(str);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

This isn't a generic way to flatten the output of `d3.nest` - you would need to consider `n` levels of nesting and probably need a recursive method. But this should work for your example.

There's some related posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270011/flatten-an-object-hierarchy-created-with-d3-js-nesting) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851383/d3-flatten-nested-data).

Comment: awesome. thank you so much for the explanation! I didn't know about flatMap()